# Mock Acces inner Created Object Verification

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mocking

I have a method in AccountService, how can I verify fields of account instance,
for instance, I want to verify that created Account has USER role,

```
 public ResponseEntity<CreateAccountResponse> createAccount(AccountCreateRequest accountCreateRequest) {

 Account account = new Account();
      account.setId(GenerateUtils.generateTokenWithPrefix(PrefixUUID.ACCOUNT));
      account.setFirstName(accountCreateRequest.getFirstName());
      account.setLastName(accountCreateRequest.getLastName());
      account.setUserName(accountCreateRequest.getEmail());
      //TODO assume that admin user should not create admin user
      account.setRole(AccountRole.USER.toString());
      account.setConfirmed(true);
      account.setLocked(false);
      account.setLoginAttempts(0);
      account.setPassword(DigestUtils.sha256Hex(accountCreateRequest.getPassword()));
  
      Account accountCreated = accountRepository.save(account);

      CreateAccountResponse createAccountResponse = CreateAccountResponse.builder().id(accountCreated.getId()).confirmed(accountCreated.getConfirmed()).firstName(accountCreated.getFirstName()).lastName(accountCreated.getLastName()).locked(accountCreated.getLocked()).loginAttempts(accountCreated.getLoginAttempts()).role(accountCreated.getRole()).userName(accountCreated.getUserName()).build();

      return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(createAccountResponse);

   }
```

Comment: Your code sets the same role value in the field of the `CreateAccountResponse` object as in the field of the `Account`. 
Isn't it enough to check that the `CreateAccountResponse` object has an `AccountRole.USER` in the body of the returned ResponseEntity?

Comment: response is created by using accountCreated instance instead of account

Comment: yes, `AccountCreated`. Why is not enough to check response body?

Comment: since accountRepository is mocked, when it returns what I provided, so it is not what I expected. I want to check interllay created account object not mocked one accountCreated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `AccountRepository` is mocked, you can catch the argument with `ArgumentCaptor` with which the repository's `save` method is called.

Smth like this:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class SimpleTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private AccountService accountService;

    @Mock
    private AccountRepository accountRepository;

    @Captor
    private ArgumentCaptor<Account> captor;


    @Test
    public void test() {
        when(accountRepository.save(captor.capture())).thenReturn(...);

        Account captorValue = captor.getValue();

        accountService.createAccount(...);

        // verify(accountRepository).save(captor.capture()); // you can also capture here and then captor.getValue()
 

        assertEquals(AccountRole.USER.toString(), captorValue.getRole());
    }
}
```

You can also create `ArgumentCaptor` direct in test method:

`ArgumentCaptor<Account> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Account.class);`

Comment: It's exactly what I was looking for. There is a saying in our culture: the mind is superior to the mind. Thanks.